# How to type a function with parameters in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have these interfaces and functions to manipulate data (email, password and, name) to send to my API.

```
interface SignUpData {
        email: string
        password: string
        name: string
    }

interface SignupProps {
    handleSignup: () => void
    errors: DeepMap<FieldValues, FieldError>
    register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>

}

const handleSignup = ({ name, email, password }: SignUpData) => {
        api
        .post("/users", {name, email, password})
}

<SignupForm
                 
                errors={errors}
                register={register}
                handleSignup={handleSubmit(handleSignup)}
            />
```

However, I am getting a problem in my last line

> handleSignup={handleSubmit(handleSignup)}

HandleSubmit is default of forms

It happens because:

Argument of type '({ name, email, password }: SignUpData) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubmitHandler'.
Parameter types '__0' and 'data' are incompatible.
The type '{ [x: string]: any; }' does not have the following properties of type 'SignUpData': email, password, namets(2345)

Comment: Can you add how you type `handleSubmit` and where you get it from?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WK71GW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Did you define the type `SubmitHandler` ? If not, then maybe you are using a library. We want to see which give you the `SignupForm` component